# Copy a file and change its name when is modified

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to make a file that run in idle until a specific file is modified.
I tried to use robocopy to make a copy but I can't modify its name.

To make it more clear:

I have a file in C:\Users\msanfili\Desktop\filetocopy named "file000" and when someone modifies it creates a copy in C:\Users\msanfili\Desktop\filecopied named "file001", when it is modified again it goes incremental, like file002 003 and so on.

As I said I tried to create a .bat file like this:

```
@ECHO OFF

ECHO completed

robocopy C:\Users\msanfili\Desktop\filetocopy C:\Users\msanfili\Desktop\copied /mot:1 /IS

PAUSE
```

I can't figure out how to go further at this point.
Is it possible to make this request as a .bat file? I can't find anyhing that help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal
ECHO completed
for /f %%s in ('dir /a-d /b /on "C:\Users\msanfili\Desktop\filetocopy\file???" ') do set "lastfilenum=%%s"
robocopy C:\Users\msanfili\Desktop\filetocopy\%lastfilenum% C:\Users\msanfili\Desktop\copied /mot:1 /IS

PAUSE
```

This assumes that what you want to do is to copy only the file with the highest sequence number.

The `setlocal` command ensures that any variables altered in the batch are restored to their original values (to prevent accumulation of changes in the current `cmd` instance)

The `dir` subcommand lists the filenames matching `file???` in the directory in alphameric sequence (/b = name only, /a-d = noo directorynames /on = sequence by name)

This list is created in memory and then processed by the `for /f %%s`, assigning each in turn to `%%s`. The very last filename found is the last one assigned to `lastfilenum` at the end of the loop.

Then simply execute your `robocopy` command.